# Concept / Mind Maps. Чем пользуетесь вы?

Tags: визуализация, диаграммы

У меня тут появилась потребность в визуализации связей между различными объектами и т.п.

Встал вопрос: чем же лучше всего пользоваться?

Платные варианты пока не ищу: за ознакомление с подобного рода программами платить не охота.
Что посоветуете?

Спасибо за внимание,
Макс.

Answer (score 1):

На js - d3js